# Stuck in another country?

Tags: overstaying

This doesn't apply to me, but I'm rather curious, and it might apply to someone else.

Spain is apparently being [reasonable about travel difficulties](https://www.abogadoextranjeriamadrid.net/en/displaced-tourists/), and I presume other countries are similar.  But part of that article is interesting: the five requirements for an extension.  I can imagine some persons being unable to meet some of the five requirements there.

**Are there any known cases of penalties for overstay when the "offender" had no way of avoiding it?  Or any country that has explicitly stated that they will enforce such penalties in spite of the "offender's" lack of options?**

Comment: I am not sure how it is going to affect. For instance, India banned all international flights after March 22. So, a person stuck abroad will have only option but to stay there.

Comment: @AnishSheela could they not fly to a nearby country and enter India by land or sea?

Comment: @phoog Only neighboring country that Indian citizen's doesn't require visa is Nepal. For srilanka, passengers are allowed only by air. That's closed now. Enough notice was given and many people, including me, chose to stay at the country of current residence than to take the risk.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn’t **exactly** answer the question as asked, but some [comments allegedly from the EU Commission](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/eu-commission-explains-what-happens-with-foreigners-unable-to-leave-due-to-travel-restrictions/) are pertinent:

“A spokesperson of the European Commission … pointed out that persons who at the expiry of their visa have already stayed 90 days in any 180-day period should be issued a national long-stay visa or a residence permit covering the prolonged stay, in the country in which they have been stranded.

“More generally, as regards, third-country nationals who are stranded in the EU and as a result overstay their short-stay or long-stay visa or their residence permit, or who stay beyond the authorized visa-free maximum period of stay, a border guard can always make an exception if properly documented,” the spokesperson said.

Comment: Still interested in examples of obstinacy as in the last paragraph of the question.